# Kendo grid sorting issue

Tags: sorting, kendo-grid

I've got it half working but it has 2 issues,

1st while is does sort when set right (sortable: true but serverSorting: false) it will only sort the present page of results

2nd with serverSorting: true it won't do any sorting but will post the parameters:-

page    1
pageSize    10
skip    0
sort[0][dir]    asc
sort[0][field]  Ward
take    10

ofc in the controller json it doesn't pickup/understand it in that format

```
public JsonResult _List(Request request, int skip, int take)
```

or

```
public JsonResult _List(List<SortDescription> sort, int skip, int take)
```

both will have count = 1 when I click to sort a column but both have field/dir null even if I just try string field, string dir.

So far as I can see I'm not correctly sending the sort data from the view to the controller but then I can't seem to find anywhere that it clearly indicates how it gets from point a to point b and is then implemented in the json.

Anybody have any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: So far I've just been setting up external sorts like dropdowns or datepickers and passing that data into the grid when I refresh on their value changes, this then hits the controller action as individual values like 'DateTime NewDate' and changing the db.Table.Where(.   This still is far from ideal and I'd like to use the built in sorting but never had any success getting it to work or understanding it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the [KendoGridBinderEx](https://github.com/StefH/KendoGridBinderEx) project which maps the query parameters to an object (KendoGridRequest).

The controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult _List(KendoGridRequest request)
{
    var entities = _employeeService.AsQueryable();
    return GetKendoGridAsJson(request, entities);
}
```